# if variable is not equal any item in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

If I have a list:

```
mobsdmg = [9, 708, 3001]
```

Then I have a document with some 1500 lines of mobs, when I read these lines inside a for loop, I want to check if any of the mobs `dmg` is equal to any of the items inside the `mobsdmg` array and if they are, do something if not, do something else.

My current problem is right now, it will check as intended, if the mob exist it will write:

```
print(mobname + "is perfect")
```

but it if it false it will make the else statement 3 times before going to the next line.

```
print(mobname + "is not a match")
print(mobname + "is not a match")
print(mobname + "is not a match")
```

I want to check on all of the items inside the array and if ALL of them are false, then program should do something.

this is the code:

```
for lines in mobs.txt:
    for items in mobsdmg:
          if items in lines:
             print(mobname + "is perfect")
          else:
             print(mobname + "is not a match")
```

Comment: Let your code do most of the explaining. That is, *post the code* that actually performs this operation in the question body.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Like... you have problem on line X, you should increment current line(get next mob) on false

Comment: You may be looking for something like `any((item in mobsdmg for item in map(int, lines.split()))`

Comment: @fernandezcuesta They should be looking for a set with a quick lookup. I feel like neat python tricks is not what op is struggling with.

Comment: Without having understood your exact scenario or problem, I think the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) or [`all` functions](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) or the `in` operator might help.

Comment: What does a line in your text file look like? Can you give some examples?

Comment: What is mob name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you can only print that the item is not a match after searching through all of the mobsdmg list. That is, you can only conclude it is not a match after the for loop. As you said, you only want to print not a match "if ALL of them are false" so your print statement can't be in the loop because you are not done checking all of mobsdmg:

The correction would be:

```
for lines in mobs:
    found = False
    for items in mobsdmg:
          if items in lines:
             print(mobname + "is perfect")
             found = True   # found a match
             break
    if not found:      # if a match wasn't found in list, print this
        print(mobname + "is not a match")
```

or alternatively, the pythonic way to do this without the additional conditional:

```
for lines in mobs:
    found = False
    for items in mobsdmg:
          if items in lines:
             print(mobname + "is perfect")
             break
    else:  
        print(mobname + "is not a match")
```

**Other issues:**

What does a line in your program look like, and what is mobs.txt? Is it a list of strings or ints? Additionally, what is mobname? You seem to never change it between lines of the loop.

Comment: This will still print a lot of duplicate messages.

Comment: @trincot Do explain how so

Comment: Just notice that `mobname` is apparently a global variable, and that in each iteration of the outer loop you print something which only has 2 possible outcomes. And so there will be lots of duplicated messages in the output.

Comment: @trincot I believe OP is pseudo coding. The print statements don't match his answer either. Either way you're making a huge assumption; the code here is valid in terms of checking the line for the items and breaking if found or printing failure if not.

Comment: @trincot For example, `mobs.txt` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: I agree it is not valid code, but even in pseudo code it does not seem useful to print the same thing over and over again. I see you added questions to your answer, which really should be put as comments, not as answer.

Comment: @trincot Replace `mobname` with `mobname(lines)`. Does that make sense? I don't think it is that complex to grasp that OP meant the mobname of the current line... In particular, in OP's original q, mobname was just the string 'mobname'. Either way, your only issues with this answer seem to be elementary or trivial.

Comment: It would indeed make more sense, but the original question needs a lot more clarification.

Comment: apologizes for not explaining myself properly. I used your example and it worked like a charm, Thanks!

Comment: @TobiasBrodersen No worries, glad to help. In the future, try an provide a complete question so that you can get a straightforward answer :) There are improvements I can make if `mobs.txt` is a list of ints as opposed to strings so let me know if  this is the case.